# Spring unit test : IllegalStateException for MultipartHttpServletRequest

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, powermock, spring-test-mvc

I have  a unit test to carry out based on the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/query")
    public class QueryController {
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/att/handle", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String handleUpload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        JsonResponseDto responseDto = null;
        HashMap<Long, String> attachmentInfoMap = null;


        String licNo = request.getParameter("licNo");
        String queId = request.getParameter("queId");

        ....
```

Please find my unit test below:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
  public class QueryControllerTest {


  @InjectMocks
private  QueryController  queryController;
private MockMvc mockMvc;
private MockMultipartHttpServletRequest request;
private MockHttpServletResponse response;
private MockHttpSession session;


   @Before
  public void setup() {

    request = new MockMultipartHttpServletRequest();

    request.setAttribute(DispatcherServlet.OUTPUT_FLASH_MAP_ATTRIBUTE, new FlashMap());
    response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
    session = new MockHttpSession();
    request.setSession(session);
    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes(request));

    //Added viewResolver to prevent circular view path error
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(queryController).setViewResolvers(viewResolver).build();

}


 @Test
public void handleUploadQueryAttachmentsOK() throws Exception {


    mockMvc.perform(post("/query/att/handle").param("queId", "123").param("licNo", "12"))
                .andExpect(status().isFound()
            );

}
```

When i execute the unit test the following error is displayed:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current request is not of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest]: org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest
```

Any idea how i can resolve the above error message please?

Comment: By setting up your test correctly. You request, response and session are useless. Those aren't used, the same for the setup you do. In your `@Before` you only should setup the `MockMvc` and that is it. Next your request is flawed as it is a plain post and not a multipart post you should change the content type.

Comment: do you really want to upload the file or just wan to send two request param "licNo" and "queId"? I didn't find any file upload code in the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to upload file using [MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload()](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#fileUpload-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) to test [MultipartHttpServletRequest](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartHttpServletRequest.html) it.

For example:

```
@Test
public void uploadImage() throws Exception {
    String data = "test-data";
    MockMultipartFile imageFile = new MockMultipartFile("image", "my-image.jpeg", "image/jpeg", data.getBytes());
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/query/att/handle").file(imageFile).param("queId", "123").param("licNo", "12"));
}
```

Here is [thread](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/124203-writing-an-integration-test-for-file-upload-controller-with-spring-test-mvc) for same discussion around it.

---

Use [@RequestParam](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) annotation to access request parameter instead of accessing them from [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html). Spring framework does it automatically just for you.

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/att/handle", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String handleUpload(@RequestParam String licNo, @RequestParam String queId, ...) throws IOException { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are testing a file upload without any file. Try to test the controller method with `mockMvc.perform(fileUpload("/query/att/handle", variables).file("filename", data))`

API doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#fileUpload-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-